# How to test function calling multiple other functions?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, express, mocha.js

I am writing an ExpressJS Middleware that modifies request object a bit and checks if user has access to that specific page. I have a problem with unit-testing it. I've written separate tests for every method except one: `handler`. How can I test `handler` function? Should I test it? Or should I just ignore it with `istanbul ignore next` as I've got every other function covered? Or maybe I should somehow rewrite my `handler` function to make it testable?

```
class Example {

constructor(request, response, next, userAccountService) {
    this.req = request;
    this.res = response;
    this.next = next;
    this.userAccountService = userAccountService;
}

removeTokenFromQuery() {
    delete this.req.query.token;
}

isValidRequest() {
    if (!this.req.secure) {
        return false;
    }

    if (typeof this.req.query.token !== 'undefined') {
        return false;
    }

    if (typeof this.req.query.unsupportedQueryParam !== 'undefined') {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

isPageAccessibleForUser() {
    return this.userAccountService.hasAccess('example');
}

async handler() {
    this.removeTokenFromQuery();

    if (!this.isValidRequest()) {
        throw new Error('Invalid request');
    }

    if (!this.isPageAccessibleForUser()) {
        this.res.statusCode(500);
        this.res.end();
        return;
    }

    this.next();
}

}
```

Then it's called as Express middleware:

```
this.app.use((res, req, next) => {
    const exampleObj = new Example(res, req, next, userAccServ);
    exampleObj.handler();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Should I test it?**

Yes, based on your example handler contains (what looks to be) some critical business logic.  It is responsible for *orchestrating*:

- removing a token from a request (security)
- determining if a request is valid (security/auth)
- determining if a page is accessible for a user (security/auth)

If this function was not tested, a future engineer may make a modification to this important function, and they wouldn't receive any feedback on their change.  Suppose that from human error they accidentally removed the isValidRequest check? or removed the `!`.  However unlikely the risk associated with this happening may be catastrophic when compared to the relatively small amount of effort necessary to test this.

**How can I test handler function?**

The next question is how you actually test this :) I would opt to test this at the lowest "level" possible **lower** (unit tes this method by invoking it directly vs **higher** (going through the express framework).

As you mentioned, there are tests for the implementations of each one of the functions that `handler` delegates to, IMO the important thing to test in `handler` is the flow and NOT the implementations (since those are already well tested).

```
describe('handler()', () => {
  it('removes token from query');
  it('errors on invalid request');
  it('returns 500 status code when page is inaccessible');
  it('continues with .next() when request is valid and page is accessible');
})
```

In order to do this I would instantiate `Example` and then patch the methods necessary in order to create the correct flow for your `handler()` tests. So for the invalid request test this might look like:

```
const example = new Example();
sinon.stub(example, "isValidRequest").returns(false);
```

If this isn't stubbed than these tests essentially duplicate the other tests (by testing the actual implementation).  Using stubs allows for the implementation of `isValidRequest` to change while still having unit test protection in `handler`